# Location of MAP (Manifold Absolute Pressure) sensor on Corsa D 2012 A14XER Engine

Tags: vauxhall, corsa, ecotec, manifold-absolute-pressure-sensor

I read online that MAP sensors are usually near/around the intake manifold areas. I have looked all around with torch light as well as feeling by my hands on areas not visible. I could not find it. On slightly different/ older models of these engines the MAP sensor is at the top UK passenger side of the intake manifold.

Any directions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it in a similar place to this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OSDPFUiTDc

Comment: Are you getting a map sensor error code?

Comment: @F Dryer: Yes I am getting p0171 error code. Looking online points to possible EVAP valve malfunction or MAP sensor malfunction.

Comment: @HandyHowie the engine on the video is Z12XEP  which is a bit different to mine. I looked at the exact place mine is completely empty on that side.